# QEMU versatile simulation failed

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, qemu, buildroot

I'm using QEMU to try to emulate the Versatile board with a buildroot-compiled kernel and FS, and have recieved the following final lines of output during boot:

```
This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Run /init as init process
mount: mounting tmpfs on /dev/shm failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting tmpfs on /tmp failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting tmpfs on /run failed: Invalid argument
input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/amba/amba:fpga/10007000.kmi/serio1/input/input2
Starting syslogd: OK
Starting klogd: OK
Initializing random number generator... random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (512 bytes read)
done.
Starting network: OK
random: crng init done
```

After using the following QEMU command:

```
qemu-system-arm -machine versatilepb -kernel zImage -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/ram0" -initrd rootfs.cpio -hda rootfs.ext2 -dtb versatile-pb.dtb -serial stdio
```

After those messages, the system stops reacting and no shell is launched.

I've configured buildroot to not execute the login prompt after boot,

[image]

So nothing happens.
When I configure the system to run a getty after boot, the same tmpfs mounting failure occurs, yet *something* happens (the login console is ran), but something must be wrong, because it doesnt accept any password and login combination I provide it with.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Start from the defconfig available in Buildroot for qemu versatile and run it as `perboard/qemu/arm-versatile/readme.txt` . It's tested, it should work fine. Then change one parameter at a time and see what breaks your boot.

Comment: Also, this troubleshooting questions are better asked on the Buildroot mailing list than here. And always send your defconfig and current git commit when reporting an issue, to help understanding and reproducing the problem.